# Deny Access to hero webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, access, access-denied

We´re currently checking on some features of SharePoint and want to create a Intranetpage.

On the homepage there should be a hero webpart where are different pages linked like for example a overview of the different existing team sites (e.g. Human Resource, Controlling etc.)

Not every user is allowed to have access to each of this team site. My question is, is it possible to

a) deny the access for the different team sites for users which aren´t allowed to have access
b) only show for the user the things (webparts like the hero webpart or things in generell) where they have access to? So that a member of e.g. the Controlling department can only see the team site of Controlling?

I hope my question and everything was understandable
Thanks in advance

Best regards
David

Comment: Hi David, 
You can trying using audience targetting to the webpart where only chosen few can see it. They way you can Deny to the site not giving them access to other parts of the site and only give them access to you homepage page.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is organizing and utilizing the SharePoint Group. I would create a SharePoint Group called "HomePage Viewers Group" which will only have read access to the homage of the site and once that is setup what I would suggest is using "Audience Targetting" to the webpart on that hompage where you dont want them to be seen by the members of the "HomePage Viewers Group", using Audience Audience targeting were are just going to limit the webpart that we wanted to hide to "HomePage Viewers Group".

Audience targeting is used to limit who can view select webpart to certain group, once used only group/users mentioned in the audience targeting can only see or interact with the targetted webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting access to modern web part is not possible in SharePoint Online. Also hiding the blocks from users with no access is not supported in Hero Web Part either.

In addition, here are my test results:

1. If we put a link to a list/library in the block, users who do not have access will enter the list/library with empty page. But they can still see some of the options in the site.
2. If we put a link to a page in the block, users who do not have access will get Access Denied error immediately.
3. Guest users with no access to the links in the web part will get Access Denied from all blocks.

I would suggest you share this idea via the SharePoint UserVoice forum: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration?category_id=203542